# Libssh remote commands not executing on server

Tags: c, exec, libssh

Having read the relevant [docs](http://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__channel.html#gac92381c4c5d4a7eab35f6e84686f033d) and [tutorials](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_command.html) and found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345232/custom-commands-with-libssh) question, I am still unable to proceed. My aplogies in advance if this is a common question. I did searches but I wasn't really sure what I was looking for...

I am experimenting with the Libssh for C in Debian.

```
rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "ls -l");
if (rc != SSH_OK) {
  ssh_channel_close(channel);
  ssh_channel_free(channel);
  return rc;
}
```

This returns SSH_OK to state that the command was sent successfully. As I understand from a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345232/custom-commands-with-libssh) question this is because the return listens for the successful  'sending' of the command. The return does not listen to see if it has been successfully executed.

**My questions is, how can I:**

- Execute the command (which by the above function presently does not execute it merely sends the command)
- Listen for it's execution
- print the returning output?

I am aware of the ssh_channel_read() function but as the command never executes, I usually get the output

```
 Read (256) buffered : 0 bytes. Window: 64000
```

Comment: Did you, as the answers in the other question, read from stderr, not just stdout, to get any potential errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at examples/exec.c in the libssh source code!